# CSS/JS- div won't stay to the right when animating to smaller width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, I have a menu bar that animates out from the left and I have a div that takes up the entirety of the page called `.message-body.` I have succeeded in animating this div to a smaller width but am having problems making sure the menu bar doesn't overlap but rather "push" the div to the right - 
my div resizes and move to the center, leaving a bunch of space to the right.

Here is my html-

```
echo '<div class="wrapperpm">';
//echo '<h1>direct message</h1>';
?>
    <div class="message-body">
        <div class="message-left">
            <ul>
//stuff
</ul>
</div>

        <div class="message-right">
            <!-- display message -->
            <div class="display-message">
                <p class ="userMessage"></p>
</div>
            <!-- /display message -->

            <!-- send message -->
            <div class="send-message">
                <!-- store conversation_id, user_from, user_to so that we can send send this values to post_message_ajax.php -->
                <input type="hidden" id="conversation_id" value="<?php echo base64_encode($conversation_id); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_form" value="<?php echo base64_encode($user_id); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_to" value="<?php echo base64_encode($user_two); ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>
<input class="button btn-primary" id="reply" type="Submit"></input> 
                <span id="error"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- / send message -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am either trying to resize/push to the right the left column `.message-left` or the whole frame `.message-body`. 
Here is what I have where the resized div goes to the center:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("home.js");
    var left=true;
    $('#menutoggle').click(function(){
        if(left)
        {
        $('.menubar').stop().animate({left: "0px"},500);
        var newwidth = $(document).width()-140;
        $('.chatframe').stop().animate({width: newwidth,left:"140px"},500);
//      $('.message-left').stop().animate({
//          width: "40px"
//          //float: right;
//      },500);

        $('.submitmessage').stop().animate({width: newwidth,left:"140px"},500);

        left=!left;
        }
        else
        {
        $('.menubar').stop().animate({left: "-140px"},500);
        var newwidth = $(document).width();
        $('.chatframe').stop().animate({width:newwidth,left:"140px"},500);

//      $('.message-left').stop().animate({
//          width: "40px"
//          //float: right;
//      },500);

        $('.submitmessage').stop().animate({width:newwidth,left:"0px"},500);
        left=!left;
        }
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

I have tried setting `float: right` in CSS on both divs but nothing is working. How can I make the divs resize while sticking to the right?

Comment: there aren't any `#menutoggle`, furthermore, the input should be closed like this: `<input />, and when you use the variable `newwidth` you should concatenate 'px' to get the result you want, if not, the value of `newwidth` is a number without meassurement units

Comment: There is I just didn't include all the html. Will that make the div stick to the right?

Comment: Probably not, but as it wasn't there we can't know if you forgot it or not